# Callback function in nextAll()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am just wondering if how can I have a call back function in `nextAll` function of jquery.

I had tried.

```
$('.selector').nextAll(function() { 
  console.log("try");
});
```

But its not working. I read the documentation in `jquery` website but I notice there are no example of callbacks.

I need the `nextAll` instead of `.each` to loop through all the next succeeding element of the selector and get the margin right of each succeeding element then animate them to right. I tried,

```
$('.selector').nextAll().animate({ right: (margin_right-100)+'px'}, 500);
//I am getting the logic here because it animates all the succeeding 
//element but the problem is that I had to replace the 
//`margin_right` variable because the elements next to the 
//selector differs on margin-right.
```

Any input guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried both?

```
$('.selector').nextAll().each(function() { 
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Yah I did tried both, Its the current setup of my code right now and when I red your answer and compare it to what i had tried so far, I notice that I am missing some values. But anyway thanks. Just need clarification here, can we not make it as `nextAll(function() { })`?